# Can I compile R-Pi programs (Qt) on R-Pi itself?

Tags: software-compilation, qt

I want to create GUI in Qt and would like to know if I can compile and test the programs on the Pi board itself. That way, I only need to connect to R-Pi using SSH and modify code, compile and test it on the board and not have to constantly upload.

Is R-Pi capable of this and will NOT take too much time for compiling? Or do I have to stick to PC cross-compiling routine. I will most probably re-compile after minor changes so number of re-compilations will probably be high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. It will compile around the same speed as a Pentium 300. Many people would consider this "too much time compiling"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way....while compiling on linux Pc,would require you a cross-compiler toolchain for ARM.

If you connecting to Pi over SSH, i would suggest you to use a cross-compile in your linux PC and use ftp to transfer file to your Pi..I hope this will be more convenient in this case.